# Family in GLM - how to choose the right one?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, ecology

When modeling data sampled in the field, I often come across the problem of determining the Family of the dependend variable for GLM (or GLMM). An example: in an ecological study, I have ~ 60 patches. I have sampled territories of an animal species within these patches as well as a set of explanatory variables. The number of territories per patch (NTP) is the dependent variable in a GLM. NTP is integer with values between 0 and 14: 
[image]
[image]

How can I test for the family of NTP? Any help appreciated as this is an issue many ecologists come across each time they conduct statistical analysis.

I am aware of [How to find the appropriate family for glm models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137232/how-to-find-the-appropriate-family-for-glm-models) being a very similar question. However, it is not answered and the test case seems a bit different.